# Bonfire Seek and Destroy- Freecodecamp Challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays

You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.

> I've these instructions:

- destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) should return [1, 1].
- destroyer([1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) should return [1, 5, 1].
- destroyer([3, 5, 1, 2, 2], 2, 3, 5) should return [1].
- destroyer([2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3) should return [].
- destroyer(["tree", "hamburger", 53], "tree", 53) should return ["hamburger"].

---

I've found code:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.splice(0,1);
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
```

---

My questions:

1. Can you explain this code in English, please?
2. Can you give a shortcut code for above challenge? please.

Comment: the code explains itself,  go to mdn to find out what are these functions doing

Comment: @RayonDabre, I hate downvoters here becouce they gave vote down without any helpful comment, and I want to know that why downvoters hate me?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this challenge using filter function, though t is recommended to use also 'indexOf' in order to compare value in array by the value to filter with.
````

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    var temp = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        temp.push(arguments[i]);
        arr = arguments[0].filter(function(value) {
            return ( value !== temp[i - 1]) ;
        });
    }
    return arr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

````

Answer (score 0):

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = arr.slice.call(arguments);
  args.splice(0,1);
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
   });
}
```

- line 1 declares the overall function used for the challenge
- line 2 converts the arguments of arr into a array variable named args, although this method doesn't work when optimizing in certain javascript platforms (optimization is basically what you're trying to do with your second question)
- line 3 removes zero (0) and one (1) from args
- lines 4 and 5 return the final result (true/false) of filtering arr for falsy and truthy by seeing whether or not an element of arg is present in arr, returning -1 if not and the element's location in arr if true

---

- this is actually relatively optimized; there is much more more-optimized code but oftentimes it is only viable on certain javascript platforms (mozilla javascript, etc.)